# web.config in js

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How to get the web.config elements value in Javascript file?
I need the value of appSettings key's value in javascript file(not in aspx). What approach should I use to get this value?
web.config

Comment: Just be careful what information you're pulling from the web.config. The value can be seen by anyone who views the source.

Answer (score 2):

On your aspx page you could do something like this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var keyName1 = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName1"]%>';
    </script>
```

Opening your entire web.config file to javascript could be a major security risk if you store things like database connection details or machine keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get them directly in a javascript file - you can use server side scripting (ASP.NET) to output them values to javascript variables and pass those to functions that are in a file, but not dynamically in a javascript file.

You could create an HTTP module that will generate a javascript file dynamically - this would have direct access to the web.config and you will be able to insert values from it dynamically as you output javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The least resource intensive would be to use something like [filter chains](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/fileset.html) in NAnt (or equiv in MSBuild—if it exists) to write the value to both your JS file and your web.config file.

This would prevent duplication of code (or configuration as it were).

The alternative (though a bit kludgy and more resource intensive) would be to put a script block above the script you need the value rendered dynamically from your aspx page using ConfigurationMangager.GetSection("web.config") in a way like this: http://schleichermann.wordpress.com/2009/01/15/dynamic-script-loading-in-html-head/

Answer (score 0):

Using an expression builder is a little more flexible than the <%= %> tag, and there's one built in for accessing appsettings. Syntax is:
`<%$ AppSettings:MyKey %>`
Read more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120206041402/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should better get it from code-behind file and pass as a hidden value.